# is there a difference between the words impfen and animpfen?

Tags: meaning

when I check from the dictionary, both "impfen" and "animpfen" seem to mean "to inoculate". but is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

The prefix *an* in *animpfen* could literally be translated to **onto** in this case. A synonym to *animpfen* would be *beimpfen* (prefix *be*).

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inokulation) lists *Animpfen* / *Beimpfung* as colloquial terms for *Inokulation*:

> Als Inokulation (umgangssprachlich auch *Animpfen* oder *Beimpfung*) wird in der Mikrobiologie und Zellbiologie das Hinzufügen eines replikationsfähigen Objekts (z. B. eine Zellkultur oder Pathogene wie Viren oder Prionen) auf eine Zellkultur bezeichnet.

It seems that this medical term is more sharply defined in German than in English. Basically *Inokulation* describes the transfer of a cell culture or pathogen **onto** another cell culture.